# How to convert the columns to numeric for removing the commas after reading a csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
df["Q28aa_1_1"]
30     2,330,000
31       2900000
32     2,550,000
33       2570000
34       2850000
35     1,000,000
36       2200000
37       2900000
```

Above is an example of dataframe column I have.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace commas and apply float by doing something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Q28aa_1_1"] = ["2,330,000", "  2900000", "2,550,000", "  2570000", "  2850000", "1,000,000", "  2200000", "  2900000"]
df["Q28aa_1_2"] = ["2,330,000", "  2900000", "2,550,000", "  2570000", "  2850000", "1,000,000", "  2200000", "  2900000"]
df["Q28aa_1_3"] = ["2,330,000", "  2900000", "2,550,000", "  2570000", "  2850000", "1,000,000", "  2200000", "  2900000"]

for column in ["Q28aa_1_1","Q28aa_1_2", "Q28aa_1_3"]:
    df[column] = df[column].str.replace(',','').apply(float)
```

output of df.head()

```
   Q28aa_1_1  Q28aa_1_2  Q28aa_1_3
0  2330000.0  2330000.0  2330000.0
1  2900000.0  2900000.0  2900000.0
2  2550000.0  2550000.0  2550000.0
3  2570000.0  2570000.0  2570000.0
4  2850000.0  2850000.0  2850000.0
```

Comment: but I need to do it for all unidentified columns in an dataframe

Comment: modified the code you should be able to pass in a list of columns and do it like this